# Loop not incrementing ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net

```
'Add items to db'
Function recordOrder()
    Dim objDT As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim objDR As System.Data.DataRow

    objDT = Session("Cart")
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim con2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim myPath2 As String
    myPath2 = Server.MapPath("faraxday.mdb")
    con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=" & myPath2 & ";"
    Dim myCommand2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim sql As String
    myCommand2.Connection = con2
    con2.Open()

    'variables'
    Dim order_date As String
    Dim coupon_ID As String
    Dim customer_id As String
    Dim quantity As String


    'variables'

    Try
        For intCounter = 0 To objDT.Rows.Count - 1



            objDR = objDT.Rows(intCounter)

            order_date = System.DateTime.Now.Date
            coupon_ID = objDR("ID")
            quantity = objDR("quantity")


            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@order_date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = order_date
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@coupon_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = coupon_ID
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = custID
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = quantity

            myCommand2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO orders(order_date, coupon_id, customer_id, quantity) VALUES ( @order_date ,@coupon_ID,@customer_id,@quantity)"



            myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        If con2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con2.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

The loop is not incrementing (intCounter). Please HELP...

Answer (score 0):

Would you not be better to use:

```
For Each objDR In objDT.Rows

            order_date = System.DateTime.Now.Date
            coupon_ID = objDR("ID")
            quantity = objDR("quantity")


            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@order_date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = order_date
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@coupon_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = coupon_ID
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = custID
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = quantity

            myCommand2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO orders(order_date, coupon_id, customer_id, quantity) VALUES ( @order_date ,@coupon_ID,@customer_id,@quantity)"



            myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Next
```

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one record? Are you sure there are no errors being swallowed? I notice your try/catch block is just taking any exceptions and throwing them out. Perhaps you could expand on that exception handler and see what comes out of the wash?

Comment: This is the exception thrown: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: there are at least three records in the data table but its not actually looping through every single row.

Comment: not the first one. the first record gets entered in to the db fine and then it just keeps adding the same row in to the db. its not incrementing at all.

Comment: it says NullReferenceException after the first row is inserted in to the db.

Answer (score 0):

'custID' is not defined anywhere ..

anyway you should insert a break point and step in with the debugger. Then watch the data to catch which statement is causing the exception. Then modify the code accordingly to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
For intCounter = 0 To objDT.Rows.Count - 1
```

Replace with:

```
For intCounter = 0 To objDT.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
```

that will increment intCounter by 1 each loop.